# what is vsim command line?

Tags: makefile, modelsim

```
 run_modelsim: $(test_info)
   $(MAKE) -C $(root_dir)/sim build_modelsim; \
   printf "" > $(test_results); \
   cd $(bld_dir); \
   vsim -c -do "run -all" +nowarn3691 \
   +test_info=$(test_info) \
   +test_results=$(test_results) \
   +imem_pattern=$(imem_pattern) \
   +dmem_pattern=$(dmem_pattern) \
   work.$(top_module) \
   $(MODELSIM_OPTS)
```

from this code I expect it to run modelsim in graphical mode. But I don’t understand what the test_results \ imem_pattern \ dmem_pattern parameters mean. Why are they transmitted to vsim if it does not have them?

Comment: The `-c` option of `vsim` launches it in Command Line Interface (CLI) mode, not graphical mode. And, of course, when launching `vsim` is CLI mode it is frequent to also pass it simulation options. This is why you see all these `+test_results=...`, `+imem_pattern=...`

Answer (score 1):

let's go options by options:

> -c

Command line mode
This is  why it is not starting in gui mode. remove that and it would do.

> -do "run -all"

This what the simulator will do. "run -all" means that it will run util the simu stops by itself.

> +nowarn3691

This is to remove a bunch a crazy modelsim warning as 
"# ** Warning: (vsim-3116) Problem reading symbols from linux-gate.so.1 : can not open ELF file."

> +test_info=$(test_info)
>   +test_results=$(test_results)
>   +imem_pattern=$(imem_pattern)
>   +dmem_pattern=$(dmem_pattern)

from the help:
"Option accessible by PLI routine mc_scan_plusargs"
This will be given to the PLI lib (weirdly the argument to enable the PLI is not present)

> work.$(top_module)

This is the entity you are going to simulate as a top.
(module: $(top_module) from lib work)

> $(MODELSIM_OPTS)

given by your makefile, so we can't know from this code